# WkWebView does not load images from raw ip addresses

Tags: image, wkwebview

if I load a local html with WKWebView (loadHTMLString) that contains an image link to a raw ip address within the current subnet (192.168.178.30), the images do not show up. It works using addresses that need to be resolved (e.g. "localhost"). Happens under iOS 8 and iOS 9. NSAppTransportSecurity is set to NSAllowsArbitraryLoads.

What is the problem? Any way to go around it?
Regards,
Markus

Comment: Type the full URL in Safari on your device and make sure that works.

Comment: This is too difficult to answer without seeing some code or more details.

Comment: @Stefan: for some reason I think I expected this is some kind of bug that maybe someone else has also experienced. I forgot to add that everything was working fine when using an UIWebView instead of the WKWebView. But thanks for your advice of just opening it in Safari - a login popup appeared that showed me that my request was rejected because of missing credentials!

Answer (score 0):

I turned out that loading the images failed because it required credentials (login) to the site. So my first guess was wrong (that it was related to raw ip addresses).

I added this selector of WKNavigationDelegate:

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential *))completionHandler
{
    NSURLCredential* credential = [[NSURLCredential alloc] initWithUser:<username> password:<password> persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone];
    completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential, self.credential);
}
```

and it worked. I think there are other ways to do it, this one is sufficient for my purpose.